# Why is my question still closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Fractal separation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4878546/fractal-separation)

Why is it still closed? I added everything, I think. Please consider that I am new to this platform.
I added motivation, backround, and gave complete definitions.
[image: The question]

Comment: You should first split your question into multiple paragraphs. This will make it more readable.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok!

Comment: I don't know what it might mean that a "Celtic Mandelbrot" is "getting separated" into infinite Mandelbrots and Mandelbars.  Perhaps you have much the same confusion about this as I do.  Your Readers have to rely on you as posing a Question to understand what is asked well enough to discern a correct Answer.  Perhaps the example you suggested of separating "the Mandelbrot set itself ... with Julia sets" in detail would help Readers respond to "is it actually a thing that can be done?".

Comment: @hardmath do you think it can be reopened now?

Comment: You can use `\bar z` for $\bar z$ for the conjugate of $z$ or `\operatorname{conjugate}`, `\operatorname{Re}(z)` for $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ or `\Re` for $\Re$, and `\to` for $\to$ instead of —>

Comment: The question has been re-opened.